# Intersection of functions $\ln(x)$ and $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: logarithms, special-functions

How to find $x$ such that $$\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Can you use numerical methods to approximate the solution?

Comment: See [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$e ^{\ln x } = e^{\frac{1}{x}} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1\Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{W(1)} $$

Where $W(1)$ is the [Omega constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OmegaConstant.html).

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}
\ln x &= \frac1x\\
x &= e^{1/x}\\
1 &= \frac1x e^{1/x}\\
W(1) &= \frac1x\\
x &= \frac1{W(1)}
\end{align*}$$
Where $W$ is the inverse function of $we^w$.

---

Alternatively,
$$\begin{align*}
x\ln x &= 1\\
(\ln x)e^{\ln x} &= 1\\
\ln x &= W(1)\\
x &= e^{W(1)}
\end{align*}$$
and WolframAlpha confirms $e^{W(1)} = \frac1{W(1)}$, which of course satisfies $\ln x = \frac1x$.

Comment: $$\frac1{\text W(1)}\approx1.763222834351896710225201776951707080436017986667473634\dots$$